# Sigabrt swift Xcode (making a timer)

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to make a stopwatch, and I can't seem to understand why I am getting a sigabrt with my application. Sorry I didn't know what to include, so I included everything.

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var minutes: Int = 0
var seconds: Int = 0
var fractions: Int = 0
var startStopWatch: Bool = true
var StopwatchString: String = ""
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {

    if startStopWatch == true {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("updateStopwatch"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startStopWatch = false
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        startStopWatch = true
    }
}

@IBAction func reset(sender: UIButton) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    display.text = "00:00.00"
}

func updateStopWatch() {
    fractions += 1
    if fractions == 100 {
        seconds += 1
        fractions = 0
    }

    if seconds == 60 {
        minutes += 1
        seconds = 0
    }


    let fractionsString = fractions > 9 ? "\(fractions)" : "0\(fractions)"
    let secondsString = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    let minutesString = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"
    StopwatchString = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString).\(fractionsString)"
    display.text = StopwatchString
}
```

Comment: FYI, your stopwatch will be grossly inaccurate the way you have it setup... Better would be to save when the user tapped the start button (in an `NSDate` object) and then update the label based on the current time minus the time the user tapped start.

Answer (score 0):

I cut and pasted your code into a project and when I tapped the start button the first line of the error message said:

> -[My.ViewController updateStopwatch]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe0034b3520

That tells you all you need to know. You send the `updateStopwatch` message to your view controller but it doesn't implement that method. I noticed though that your ViewController does implement an `updateStopWatch` method. Looks like a basic capitalization error to me.

Always, always, always, read at least the first line of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some fixes:

+I changed the timer variable initially to nil - it will be saved in the start function.

+Your if statement in the start function looked like this:

if startStopWatch == true
But it should be like this:

if (startStopWatch)

Hope this helpes :)

```
var timer = nil
var minutes = 0
var seconds = 0
var fractions = 0
var startStopWatch = true
var StopwatchString = ""
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
    if (startStopWatch == true) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("updateStopwatch"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startStopWatch = false
//I added one thing. If the start button is pushed the text will change to stop. You can change this if you like.
        sender.setTitle("Stop", forState: .Normal)
//
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        startStopWatch = true
    }
}

@IBAction func reset(sender: UIButton) {
    display.text! = "00:00.00"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    display.text! = "00:00.00"
}

func updateStopWatch() {
    fractions++
    if (fractions == 100) {
        seconds++
        fractions = 0
    }

    if (seconds == 60) {
        minutes++
        seconds = 0
    }


    var fractionsString = fractions > 9 ? "\(fractions)" : "0\(fractions)"
    var secondsString = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    var minutesString = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"
    StopwatchString = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString).\(fractionsString)"
    display.text! = StopwatchString
}
```